# Solution of a Partial Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

**Problem statement**

Solve $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-x\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=y$ using the change of variables $\left\{\begin{matrix}
u=ax^2+y  \\
v=x  
\end{matrix}\right.$ for a suitable choice of $a$.

**Solution**(Not correct solution according to key)

Using the chain rule we arrive at:
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-x\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=[\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}]-x[\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}]=(2ax-1)\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}=y$ so a suitable choice is $a=\frac{1}{2}$.

$\Rightarrow \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}=y$

Now since $dv=dx$ it follows that $f(x,y)=xy+\phi(x)$ and inserting at the initial problem and solve for $\phi(x)$ we arrive at the solution $f(x,y)=xy+\frac{x^3}{3}+C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did a mistake when computing your expression. The variable $x$ multiplies $f_{u}(v,u)$, so that the correct expression is
\begin{equation}
f_u(v,u) x (2 a -1)+f_v (v,u)= y
\end{equation}
Now expressing x and y as function of v, u:
\begin{equation}
f_u(v,u) v (2 a -1)+f_v (v,u)= u - a v^2
\end{equation}
if you set $a=\frac{1}{2}$ you get:
\begin{equation}
f_v (v,u)= u - \frac{1}{2} v^2
\end{equation}
Which has the solution:
\begin{equation}
f(v,u)= u v - \frac{v^3}{6} + K(u)
\end{equation}
Now you can go back by replacing $v$ by $x$ and y by $y + \frac{1}{2} x^2$. You get:
\begin{equation}
f(x,\frac{x^2}{2}+y)=\frac{x^3}{3}+x y +K(\frac{x^2}{2}+y)
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you. But that is a solution in $f(u,v)=f(x^2/2+y,x)$. How can we find the solution in $f(x,y)$?